# C Windows API determine if user is inactive inclusive of playing media

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have written some code that makes use of a timer checking when the last user input was and prints it out to Visual Studio's debug console.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD InactiveThreshold; // The allowable amount of inactive time milliseconds
BOOL Inactive;

SYSTEMTIME CurrentTime(char *ddmmyyyy, char *hhmmss)
{
    SYSTEMTIME lt;

    GetLocalTime(&lt);
    snprintf(ddmmyyyy, 11, "%d/%d/%d", lt.wDay, lt.wMonth, lt.wYear);
    snprintf(hhmmss, 9, "%d:%d:%d", lt.wHour, lt.wMinute, lt.wSecond);

    return lt;
}

void DebugOutput(char *ddmmyyyy, char *hhmmss)
{
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("\n\n"));
    OutputDebugString(ddmmyyyy);
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("  --  "));
    OutputDebugString(hhmmss);
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("  :  "));
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("Inactive"));
}

void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT unt, UINT_PTR id, DWORD current_time)
{
    LASTINPUTINFO li;
    SYSTEMTIME lt;
    DWORD TimeSinceInput, RemainingTime;
    char ddmmyyyy[11], hhmmss[9];

    // Timers continue to expire, so we need to stop it first.
    KillTimer(NULL, id);

    li.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
    GetLastInputInfo(&li);

    TimeSinceInput = current_time - li.dwTime;
    if (TimeSinceInput > InactiveThreshold)
    {
        // [Also find a way to check if audio or video was playing during the user inactive period]
        if (!(Inactive))
        {
            // Set flag so it only outputs that it is inactive once during an inactive period
            Inactive = TRUE;

            lt = CurrentTime(ddmmyyyy, hhmmss);

            // [Find way to print the start of the inactive period as timestamp, 
            // subtracting InactiveThreshold from current time]

            DebugOutput(ddmmyyyy, hhmmss);

        }
        // [Change below so once Inactive, stop timer and instead set event loop 
        // to check for user input(keyboard / mouse) to end the inactive period
        // and output timestamp of the end of the inactive period]

            SetTimer(NULL, 0, InactiveThreshold, &TimerProc);
    }
    else
    {
        Inactive = FALSE;
        RemainingTime = InactiveThreshold - TimeSinceInput;
        SetTimer(NULL, 0, RemainingTime, &TimerProc);
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    Inactive = FALSE;
    InactiveThreshold = 30000;  // 30 seconds

    SetTimer(NULL, 0, InactiveThreshold, &TimerProc);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ideally it should print when the timestamp of the start of the inactive period was, then when the user is active again to print the timestamp of when the inactive period finished. However there's three main issues (also indicated in the code with square bracket comments //[] ):

- GetLastInputInfo() doesn't take into account if the user is playing media (ex: watching a video or listening to audio in Google Chrome)
- When determining the system is inactive, how would you subtract the InactiveThreshold time in ms from the current timestamp to determine the start of the inactive period as the data types used are different
- How could you set an event callback to wait for user mouse/keyboard input again once it is decided that the user is inactive?

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag from your post. There is nothing in what you've written that has anything to do with C++. The title and the entirety of the code is strictly C. Please do not tag spam with tags that are not directly relevant to your post. A carrot and a car and a cat are not the same thing because they all start with *ca*. Tags have meaning here, so please use only those that actually apply. Thanks.

Comment: @ken: That's an arbitrary choice. By the same token, there's nothing in the question that doesn't make it C++. So why tag one but not the other. Either one equally applies. I'm reverting your changes.

Comment: @mic: The current time can be requested in multiple ways. If you need to timestamp that's compatible with the value returned by `GetLastInputInfo` you need to call `GetTickCount`.

Comment: "*How could you set an event callback to wait for user mouse/keyboard input again once it is decided that the user is inactive?*" - new user activity can be detected using `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()`

Answer (score 1):

> GetLastInputInfo() doesn't take into account if the user is playing
>   media (ex: watching a video or listening to audio in Google Chrome)

As I understand, system itself track activity only as whatever is available from `GetLastInputInfo()`.

Cases like "user is watching video" are handled by sending `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `SC_SCREENSAVE` or `SC_MONITORPOWER`, so that screen does not go blank if application swallows such message instead of passing to `DefWindowProc`. Or alternatively by `SetThreadExecutionState` with `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED`

Cases like background audio are handled by `SetThreadExecutionState` with `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED`.

This all means that user inactivity does happen, but some other conditions prevent from taking actions on this inactivity.

I'm afraid an application cannot reliably detect all such conditions.